# Change Design of the buttons

Tags: python, pyqt4, raspberry-pi

I'm developing a program in python with a gui in pyqt4.
Now i have some porblem with the design of my buttons.
They have some style like windows 98 and i don't like that.
I have change my theme of my raspberry but nothing changed in my python application.
The theme changed my raspberry but not my application.
I use LXDE on my raspberry.
Do have anybody some solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can change style of the Qt Application using one of the built in styles from Qt, for example you can use:

```
app.setStyle('plastique')
```

There are QWindowsStyle, QPlastiqueStyle, QCleanlooksStyle, QGtkStyle, QMotifStyle, QCDEStyle...

or you can use QSS (Qt Style Sheets) to theme your application, docs are here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html